# Mutation validation ids in input for entities from another service. GraphQL Apollo Federation

Tags: graphql, backend, apollo, apollo-federation, apollo-gateway

I need to validate ids from mutation
There's example

```
type Query @extends{
    calendars(
        users: [Int]
        resources: [Int]
        workgraph_types: [Int]
        provide_services: Boolean
        date_from: String
        date_to: String
        paging: PagingInput
    ): CalendarList! @verifyResource
}
```

Need to validate ids for resources. I have resource in another microservice. I need to check that resource exists in another microservice. I want to do it, using apollo federation. Can i? How?)

I tried to do it, using custom directives. But, as i know, i need to make resolvers for them in each microservice

I expect that this validation delegate checking that it exists to another microservice (resource owner)